# How to generate Json data using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I want to generate JSON like below :

```
{
 "Users" :
 [
   {
       "userData":
    [
      {
        "id" : "1",
        "name" : "zbc"
      },
      {
        "id" : "2",
        "name" : "vyz"
      }
    ],
    "Main id" : "ae44",
    "Main dept" : "Bmoa"
   },
  {
       "userData":
    [
      {
        "id" : "5",
        "name" : "as"
      },
      {
        "id" : "7",
        "name" : "ss"
      }
    ],
    "Main id" : "ae99",
    "Main dept" : "Bsds"
   }
]
}
```

Now this array of userData is come with using DataSet.

I have used the below code :

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));

        DataSet dsDept = new DataSet();
        dsDept = cls.ReturnDataSet("sp_users",
            new SqlParameter("@Field", "*"),
            new SqlParameter("@TblNm", "Users"));

       for (int idsDept = 0; idsDept < dsDept.Tables[0].Rows.Count; idsDept++)
      {

          string mainId = dsDept.Tables[0].Rows[idsDept]["id"].ToString();
          string mainDept = dsDept.Tables[0].Rows[idsDept]["dept"].ToString();


          DataSet ds = new DataSet();
          ds = cls.ReturnDataSet("sp_users",
              new SqlParameter("@Field", "*"),
              new SqlParameter("@TblNm", "Users"),
              new SqlParameter("@Where", "where mainid = '" + mainId + "' "));

        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["value"].ToString(), ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["notification_time"].ToString());

        }
    }

        UserContainer cont = new UserContainer ();
        cont.usersdetails = dt;
```

With the above code i am getting output like below which is not proper according to my output expectation.

```
{
    "userData": [
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "asdasd"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "wew"
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "name": "qqqq"
        }
    ]
}
```

But this above code is not generating same JSON as i want.

How can i generate this type of JSON ?

Comment: I don't see the code that generates the 'wrong' JSON in your post? Showing the JSON that does get generated would be helpful too

Comment: @deepak: Your code generates no json.

Comment: Here you have a json that requires an array of User, each User has an array of UserData with two fields Mainid and MainDept. How do you get the MainId and MainDept values required by each User?

Comment: Mainid and MainDept is also getting with the use of other DataSet.

Comment: And where is the other dataset? In which table are these values? Sorry but you should try to complete this question with all the relevant information if you want to get reasonable help

Comment: other dataset table name is => userdataDept

Comment: All right but we need to know how the two dataset are related to each other. We need to loop on the userdataDept and extract all the userdata from the other dataset

Comment: Ok. I am updating my question with both dataset and loop.

Comment: @Steve i have update both dataset and its loop . Please check it.

Comment: Still no connection between the DataSet and JSon.

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Now I am more confused than before. You call the same *sp_users* but the second time you seems to add a where condition. So I expect the first call to already contains the information required and there is no need to call again the database. Finally, the internal loop now uses a field named _value_ and a field named _notification_time_ Nothing to do with the _id_ and _name_ expected by the json. Could you provide the exact fields names of the first table returned by the call to the *sp_users* stored procedure?

Comment: @Steve Thanks for your time ! i have solved it with help of json2csharp.com

Answer (score 1):

Using http://json2csharp.com/ I get the classes

```
public class UserData
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public List<UserData> userData { get; set; }
    public string MainId { get; set; }
    public string MainDept { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Note, you can't have a space in a property name.

---

Simply populate `RootObject` and use JSON.Net to serlialize it. I don't see why you'd use a `DataTable`/`DataSet` for anything, except perhaps, passing a Table Valued Parameter with ADO.Net.

If you wan't a simple, and fast way to populate these objects from a database that supports SQL I'd consider [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper).

Comment: Thanks it helps me alot.

Comment: You can use `[JsonProperty]` attributes on the properties to give them a JSON name that contains a space.  For example `[JsonProperty("Main id")]`